# Using fragment.setEnterTransition works but the same animation occurs on Exit as well, although i have not set any exitTransition

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction, fragment-transitions

Following code works for enter animation and exit animation as well, i do not want it to animate on exit. What am i doing wrong here. ?

```
        MyProfileFragment profileFragment = new MyProfileFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, profileFragment);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            profileFragment.setEnterTransition(new Fade().setDuration(200));
            //profileFragment.setExitTransition(new Fade().setDuration(0));
        }

        ft.addToBackStack("profile");
        ft.commit();
```

Comment: use this method `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);`

Comment: don't wanna use custom animations. :|

Answer (score 0):

By default, the value passed into `Fragment.setEnterTransition` is reversed when that Fragment exits. To avoid this, you can assign `null` or another value to `Fragment.setExitTransition`.